# Django Python: global name 'render' is not defined

Tags: python, django, render

I am getting an error in my Django project, and it looks like it's coming from my `views.py` file:

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def get_date_time(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render(request, 'date_time.html', {'current_date': now})
```

Error: `global name 'render' is not defined`

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to import [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) from [`django.shortcuts`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#module-django.shortcuts) as it is not a built-in function.:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

Comment: Do you have copied/pasted the typo "shorcuts" instead of "shortcuts"?

Comment: @Yoni201 Fixed the typo.

Comment: For me, it didn't work. "from django.http import HttpResponse" worked for me as answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975206/httpresponse-error-with-google-webmater-tools (and I was following this tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are following the Django tutorial and have this error but already have the import, it could be because the web server needs to be reloaded. The changes in code won't be reflected until `runserver` is ran again.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
t = get_template('document.html')
html = t.render(Context({'variable': value}))
return HttpResponse(html)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17906075/3) to the question [Django Python: global name 'render' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906075/django-python-global-name-render-is-not-defined) by the OP [TheProofIsTrivium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1822494/theproofistrivium) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>