# HttpResponse error with Google Webmater Tools

Tags: django, google-search-console

I'm trying to use Google Webmaster Tools following this [guide](https://gun.io/blog/setting-up-google-webmaster-tools-with-python-django/)

I implemented my url as it says

```
(r'^googlece9fb428b0c84a39\.html$', lambda r: HttpResponse("google-site-verification: googlece9fb428b0c84a39.html", mimetype="text/plain")),
```

But I'm getting the following error when acessing the url:

```
NameError at /googlece9fb428b0c84a39.html
global name 'HttpResponse' is not defined
```

Comment: Have you imported HttpResponse from django.http?

Comment: thank you! just need to import it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`from django.http import HttpResponse`

Answer (score 0):

just need to import HttpResponse from django.http